Data Replication across data center for banking transactions
Suppose I am developing a backend for Transaction management system. When a banking transaction happen which when mapped to Db transaction, does it include write logs to different geos. If it does not what happen if one data center crashes before data is replicated to other DC.
Or generally banking transactions are said to be successful only if they are written across geos?
Geos here is loose term for Data Center.
